# Would it have been possible for Harry to kill Voldemort by drinking liquid luck?

Tags: harry-potter

Sorry if this can only be answered speculatively.

In *The Half-Blood Prince*, Professor Slughorn gave Harry a bottle of Felix Felicis, also known as Liquid Luck, after Harry successfully created a Drink of Despair.

Would it have been possible for Harry to drink the liquid luck and then go kill Voldemort without first destroying the Horcruxes?

Comment: I put it alongside the 'time turner' as something that inexplicably everyone forgets about.... http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForgottenSuperweapon

Comment: In *Half-Blood Prince* chapter 1, the Prime Minister asks ‘But for heaven's sake – you're *wizards*! You can do *magic*! Surely you can sort out – well – *anything*!’

Comment: @Richard: You mean such as veritaserum? As in, when a boy claims that Voldemort is back some 3 years earlier, or even when the same boy says Pettigrew is alive why don't the most powerful wizards in the world think about _asserting_ that claim using veritaserium (or Ye Olde Mappe that showeth ye true names) and trivially use _deus ex machina_ to go back in time and capture Pettigrew, preventing everything else from happening?

Comment: @Damon - Don't even get me started on the marauder's map..http://www.quickmeme.com/img/cd/cdf3c4dab90165f49e70c271689588cb133336e8178f7f3145c7f17665011754.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you remember, when Harry did use the Liquid Luck, it caused him to spontaneously decide to go to Hagrid's, which (luckily) turned out to lead him to Slughorn, and end up getting Slughorn drunk enough to divulge the memory. From this, I would say that if he used the Liquid Luck, he would most likely just stumble upon each horcrux, catching Mundungus on the way out of Grimmuald Place, instead of having already sold the locket, maybe finding that Bellatrix had decided to take the cup out of the vault for safe keeping the very night he ran into her at the Malfoy's, etc.